# Display information based on the autocomplete selected value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have dynamic text field at [Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/1/) and I have done the autocomplete part for my item part no.

```
$ (document).ready(function() {
    $("#addField").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");                   
        var fpartNo = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"erfq_partNo[]\" class=\"partNumber\"/>");
        var fDescription = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"erfq_desc[]\" disabled/>");                   
        var fPrice = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"erfq_price[]\" disabled style=\"width:80px\"/>");   
        // remove textboxes and dropdown boxes
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fpartNo);
        fieldWrapper.append(fDescription);
        fieldWrapper.append(fPrice);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);

        $(".partNumber").autocomplete({         
            minLength:1,
            source: 'readPart.php',
             select: function(event, ui){
                var selected = ui.item.value;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**readPart.php**

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$getPartSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM eitem_item where eitem_item_part_no LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY eitem_item_part_no" );
while($Partdata_row = base_fetch_array($getPartSQL))
if (base_num_rows($getPartSQL)!= 0)
{
    $data[] = $Partdata_row['eitem_item_part_no'];
} 
echo json_encode($data);
```

The first text field is uses for entering the part No. 
My question is once the part no has been entered, the other relevant information (description and price) will be displayed at the other readonly text fields which the data are extract from my database. I have no idea what to continue with this `select: function(event, ui){`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, if you want to get the data on the basis of `part #` from `database` you can trigger an `ajax` call on `blur` of `text box` part number.

you can do something like this

```
$("#partNum").blur(function(){
    var part = $("#partNum").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url:'/echo/js/?js='+part,    //url to your database fetcher code.
        complete: function (response) {     //response contains what you got from pap page
            $('textarea#des').val(response.responseText);    //set textarea and textbox value popping out from db file
        }
    });
});
```

Here is `HTML` snippet to this request.

```
<input type = 'text' id = 'partNum' name = 'parts' />
<textarea id = "des" name = 'description' disabled></textarea>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dg52au6u/)**

this will work on `blur` means when clicked outside the `textbox`. But if you want to get real time data(while user is typing) then you've to bombard the `ajax` requests on `keyup` event.

something like this:

```
$("#partNum").keyup(function(){
    var part = $("#partNum").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url:'/echo/js/?js='+part,
        complete: function (response) {
            $('textarea#des').val(response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/q5ehkutn/)**

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Mubin, you gave me an idea and I took some of your code as my references. Thank you!

Comment: glad that helped @Sollo :)